# Can't grant all tables permission denied

Tags: postgresql, permission-denied

I can't grant a new role on all tables. A table denies the query. How can I grant the user to be able run this command?

```
CREATE ROLE userrole123 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'userrole123' VALID UNTIL '2024-01-07 09:37:39.0' INHERIT;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO userrole123;
```

Output

```
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for table test
```

I run this command `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to myusername` but it did not solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Whoever is executing the GRANT lacks the authority to do it.  Is this user a superuser?  Does it own the table public."test"?

Comment: It is an AWS RDS Postgres DB so there's no super user. This is a master user. How can I grant this user to get that authority? @jjanes

Comment: Maybe you should retag to `AWS-RDS` , or something?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) is pretty outspoken there:

> Ordinarily, only the object's owner (or a superuser) can grant or revoke privileges on an object. However, it is possible to grant a privilege “with grant option”, which gives the recipient the right to grant it in turn to others.

So obviously the user who is running the `GRANT` is neither a superuser, nor does it own `test`, nor has it been granted the `SELECT` privilege `WITH GRANT OPTION`.